# Call to GetOpenFileNameA causes common dialog error 2

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to open a dialog box using GetOpenFileNameA. However, the dialog does not open. Instead, I get a nice CommDlgError 2. Searching Google and StackOverflow for this error did not produce any helpful results.

Confusingly, this code works on a school computer that also uses Visual Studio, albeit a different version.

**Note:** All variables not declared in this block of code are "global" variables that are only accessible within the main code module.

```
void GetInputFile()
{
    char szFileNameIN[MAX_PATH];
    char szFileNameOUT[MAX_PATH];

    // get the input file name
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    ZeroMemory(&fInputPath, sizeof(fInputPath));
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = LPWSTR("Any File\0*.*\0");
    ofn.lpstrFile = LPWSTR(fInputPath);
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = LPWSTR(szFileNameIN);
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = LPWSTR("Select an input File");
    ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
    if (GetOpenFileNameA(LPOPENFILENAMEA(&ofn))) // user selected an input file
    {
    }
    else {
        // Get error
        TCHAR error[MAX_LOADSTRING];
        wsprintf(error,TEXT("%i"),CommDlgExtendedError());
        MessageBox(NULL,error,TEXT("ERROR"),MB_OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: Using the LPWSTR and LPOPENFILENAMEA casts only stopped the compiler from telling you that you did it wrong, it did not stop you from doing it wrong.  If you *really* don't care about localization then use OPENFILENAMEA instead.  And remove the casts.

Comment: You're calling the ANSI version of the function with the structure set up for the Unicode version. Why would you expect that **not** to fail?

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for the input.

Comment: @KenWhite: I took this code from my professor's sample.

Comment: If it's straight from your professor's sample, you should be asking your professor why their code doesn't work instead of asking us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those awful `(LPWSTR)` casts tell me that you are compiling with `UNICODE` defined, so the `OPENFILENAME` struct you are using is actually `OPENFILENAMEW`; given that you are using `GetOpenFileNameA`, you have to use `OPENFILENAMEA` (or use straight `GetOpenFileName` with wide strings).

(and remember that, as a rule of thumb, if you have to cast pointers to/from anything different than `void *` and similar, you are probably doing something wrong; adding pointer casts will only silence the compiler, not make the error go away)

Comment: Actually, it's the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol, that controls the generic-text mappings of the Windows API. `_UNICODE` is used for the CRT. And if you wish to use wide character strings, then the API to call is `GetOpenFileNameW`; `GetOpenFileName` is a macro, that should only be used with the generic-text mappings (or really, not at all).

Comment: `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE`: wops, fixed, I always forget who is who. `TCHAR`: 15 years ago I would have agreed, today there's no longer any benefit in `TCHAR`s besides consistency with older code. `TCHAR`s have a tendency to infect your code, aren't as widely supported as `wchar_t`in library code (there's `wstring` but no `tstring`), the CRT mappings look ugly (`_tcslen`, seriously? also, ugh `_T`). Thus, unless you still target Win 9x, I would either just use the "undecorated" APIs (easier to read) assuming they are W, or write my own UTF8->UTF16 wrappers and work with UTF8 chars everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `TCHAR` version of `OPENFILENAME`.  Since you are assigning Unicode string pointers to its fields, that means your project is being compiled with `UNICODE` defined, so `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t` and `OPENFILENAME` maps to `OPENFILENAMEW`.  But you are using ANSI character buffers and the ANSI version of `GetOpenFileName()`, and using incorrect type-casts all over the place.

So get rid of *all* the type-casts, and then either:

1. use proper `TCHAR` types and APIs for everything:

   ```
   void GetInputFile()
   {
       TCHAR szFileNameIN[MAX_PATH];
       TCHAR szFileNameOUT[MAX_PATH];

       // get the input file name
       OPENFILENAME ofn;
       ZeroMemory(&fInputPath, sizeof(fInputPath));
       ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
       ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
       ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
       ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("Any File\0*.*\0");
       ofn.lpstrFile = fInputPath; // must be TCHAR[]...
       ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
       ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileNameIN;
       ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
       ofn.lpstrTitle = TEXT("Select an input File");
       ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
       if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)) // user selected an input file
       {
       }
       else
       {
           // Get error
           TCHAR error[MAX_LOADSTRING];
           wsprintf(error, TEXT("%i"), CommDlgExtendedError());
           MessageBox(NULL, error, TEXT("ERROR"), MB_OK);
       }
   }
   ```
2. use proper `CHAR`/`WCHAR` types and APIs for everything:

   ```
   void GetInputFile()
   {
       WCHAR szFileNameIN[MAX_PATH];
       WCHAR szFileNameOUT[MAX_PATH];

       // get the input file name
       OPENFILENAMEW ofn;
       ZeroMemory(&fInputPath, sizeof(fInputPath));
       ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
       ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
       ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
       ofn.lpstrFilter = L"Any File\0*.*\0";
       ofn.lpstrFile = fInputPath; // must be WCHAR[]...
       ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
       ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileNameIN;
       ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
       ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Select an input File";
       ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
       if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn)) // user selected an input file
       {
       }
       else
       {
           // Get error
           WCHAR error[MAX_LOADSTRING];
           wsprintfW(error, L"%i", CommDlgExtendedError());
           MessageBoxW(NULL, error, L"ERROR", MB_OK);
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   void GetInputFile()
   {
       CHAR szFileNameIN[MAX_PATH];
       CHAR szFileNameOUT[MAX_PATH];

       // get the input file name
       OPENFILENAMEA ofn;
       ZeroMemory(&fInputPath, sizeof(fInputPath));
       ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
       ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
       ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
       ofn.lpstrFilter = "Any File\0*.*\0";
       ofn.lpstrFile = fInputPath; // must be CHAR[]...
       ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
       ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileNameIN;
       ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
       ofn.lpstrTitle = "Select an input File";
       ofn.Flags = OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
       if (GetOpenFileNameA(&ofn)) // user selected an input file
       {
       }
       else
       {
           // Get error
           CHAR error[MAX_LOADSTRING];
           wsprintfA(error, "%i", CommDlgExtendedError());
           MessageBoxA(NULL, error, "ERROR", MB_OK);
       }
   }
   ```